# I didnt get the desired result with wampserver in the <? syntax.Why?

Tags: php, syntax, wampserver

I am using wamp server 2.0 on windows XP with PHP version 5.2.5 when I am using the following code

```
<?
  echo "hai";
?>
```

I am not getting the output. But when I am using

```
<?php
  echo "hai";
?>
```

Got the result.If I am using the first one in Linux server I got the output.One of my large project like the first one in all php pages.I want to configure with wamp.SO if first coding needs to work what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first guess is your `php.ini` isn't configured for this. The parameter `short_open_tag` is responsible for it.

Edit your php.ini, search the following parameter and activate it (or add it when its missing there):

```
short_open_tag = On
```

More details are in the [php-manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php).

Answer (score 0):

i'm not using wamp now, maybe you can test solution from http://www.wampserver.com/phorum/read.php?2,50473,50474#msg-50474.
Wish this can help you. :)